# find a specific question on Main

Tags: support, specific-question, search

I just answered another question on $2^4 = 4^2.$

Does anyone know how to find the question where someone had a decent conjecture on all **rational** solutions to $x^y = y^x?$

Turns out all rational solutions are, with an integer $n,$

$$ x = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n,  \; \;  y = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1},   $$
where $$  x^y = y^x = x^x \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^x $$ need not be rational.  I would say $n \neq -1$ in any case. Not quite sure whether $n \leq -2$ give repeats of the solutions with $n \geq 1.$ Alright, given $n \geq 1,$ it is easy enough to see that we get a repeat from $-1-n.$ So, we might as well restrict to $n \geq 1.$

Comment: I'll add that there is also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y), which asks about the same equation for integers, but the answers provide also some information about rational solutions. And there are lots of linked questions to that one. (In fact, it is linked from the post mentioned by Daniel Fischer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you mean [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785836/find-all-positive-rational-solutions-to-xy-yx), found per google search:

> rational solutions x^y = y^x site:math.stackexchange.com

[rational solutions x^y = y^x site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/#q=rational+solutions+x%5Ey%20%3D%20y%5Ex+site:math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You are my new god. Do you have any religious principles that would make that a problem?

Comment: It would force me to seriously doubt my existence. But that's not a problem.

Comment: I think you did the right thing studying mathematics.

Comment: I tried your string in Giggle, it actually worked, exponents and everything.

Comment: Maybe also using quotes to get the exact phrase might be useful for similar searches:
[rational solutions "x^y=y^x" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/#q=rational+solutions+%22x%5Ey%3Dy%5Ex%22+site:math.stackexchange.com).